# Can I create CNAME for www.example.com in zone file for example.org?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, linode

I am using `example.org` in this question only as an example. In my real zone file, I have a real domain instead of `example.org`.

This is how my zone file looks right now.

```
$TTL 14400
@   IN  SOA ns1.linode.com. example\.org.gmail.com. 2017061008 14400 14400 604800 14400
@       NS  ns1.linode.com.
@       NS  ns2.linode.com.
@       NS  ns3.linode.com.
@       NS  ns4.linode.com.
@       NS  ns5.linode.com.
@           A   101.101.101.101
www         A   101.101.101.101
@           AAAA    1001:1001::1001:1001:1001:1001
www         AAAA    1001:1001::1001:1001:1001:1001
www.example.com         CNAME   example.org.
www.example.net         CNAME   example.org.
```

Do you see anything incorrect in this zone file?

I ask this because nslookup of `example.org` and `www.example.org` succeeds but nslookup of `www.example.com` and `www.example.net` fails. What am I missing?

Note 1: I have registered `example.com`, `example.org` as well as `example.net` and in their `whois` information, the `Name Server` fields are pointing to `ns1.linode.com`, `ns2.linode.com`, etc.

Note 2: I am managing my zone using the Linode DNS Manager web-based interface. The output block above is obtained from the zone dump that Linode DNS Manager provides me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible. In the zone `example.org`, you can only define records for that domain.

You would have to define the record `www.example.com` in the zone file for `example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have  `www.example.com. CNAME` (or `www CNAME`) in the zone file for the same domain `example.com.`. Without the tailing dot you'd just speficy a subdomain for the (currently missing) `$ORIGIN`, e.g. `www.example.com.example.org`.

The *canonical name* `CNAME` creates an alias of any record, not only `A`. Therefore, I'd recommend using `www.example.com. CNAME www.example.org.` instead of the plain domain in order to avoid aliasing possible `MX`, `TXT` etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
www.example.com         CNAME   example.org.
www.example.net         CNAME   example.org.
```

Is wrong as I think - in this case You have defined something like that:

```
www.example.com.example.org 
www.example.net.example.org
```

If You want to point www.example.net and www.example.com to IP declared for example.org you should add dots at end eg:

```
www.example.com.         CNAME   example.org.
www.example.net.         CNAME   example.org.
```